# How big can my spark RDD joins be?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have 100 executors with 4 GB memory per executor and 10 GB disk space per executor node. What can be the maximum size of my RDD or DF joins in Spark?

I am assuming the maximum size of my combined input can only be less than (100 * 4 + 100 * 10)GB. 1400GB that is. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm confused... If you have 10GB of disk and only 4GB of RAM, how would you ever fill memory+spill to disk more data than you have available in hardware? In otherwords, you don't multiply anything, as you're limited by your smallest available executor, which can die from out of memory exceptions during a join.

Answer (score 0):

1400GB can't be your maximum size. You have to take temp files that occupy some space, other services that need some memory and space to operate into account.